# How do I read txt file if I have multiple attributes?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a class to read my txt file with a few lines, for example:

Facial Lotion, 1 , 2, 0.1

Moisturiser Lotion, 2, 3, 0.2

Toner Lotion, 3, 4, 0.3

Aloe Vera Lotion, 4, 5, 0.4

I created a class call Lotion with attributes name(string), productNo(int), productRating(int), and productDiscount(double, and I create another class call ListOfLotion and add in an arraylist of Lotion.

my problem is how do i get my ListOfLotion class to use the values in txt file and put it in my arraylist.

I tried to use indexOf for name till the next one but i got error,
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 17

also is there anyway i could separate all four value and make sure they are store properly for example, Facial Lotion is store as the name and 1 is store as prodcuctNo.

```
public void addListOfLotion(){

    ArrayList<Lotion> lotion = new ArrayList<Lotion>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Desktop/Lotion.txt");

    while(scanner.hasNext()){

     String readLine = scanner.nextLine();

     int indexProductNo = readLine.indexOf(',');

     int indexOfProductRating = readLine.indexOf(',');

     double indexOfProductDiscount = readLine.indexOf(',');

      lotion.add(new Lotion(readLine.substring(0, indexOfProductNo),0,0,0));

    }scanner.close();

    }

Got this error as result: 
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 17
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at ListOfVenues.addListOfLotion(ListOfLotion.java:42)
```

Is it beccause I put readLine,indexOf(',') as every readLine, it just stop at the first ','? Anyway I could effectively let java know that between this and this index is for name, and between this and this index is for productNo?

thanks guys really appreciate it.

Comment: If this is a copy-paste then the problem is that "indexOfProductNo" is not declared here and is used from somewhere else. Otherwise can you make sure that you copy-paste the exact code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the lines are comma-separated lists you could use `split()` to split the line into the single variables.
Another thing to consider is that `Scanner("file.txt")` doesn't read the indicated text file but just the given `String`. You have to create a `File` object first.

```
File input = new File("Desktop/Lotion.txt");
Scanner scanner;
scanner = new Scanner(input);
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String readLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] strArray = readLine.split(",");
    int indexOfProductNo = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1].trim());
    int indexOfProductRating = Integer.parseInt(strArray[2].trim());
    double indexOfProductDiscount = Double.parseDouble(strArray[3].trim());
    lotion.add(new Lotion(strArray[0],indexOfProductNo,indexOfProductRating,indexOfProductDiscount));
}
```

Comment: Good catch with the `Scanner`, I didn't even notice that

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0hB9l/1)):

```
([\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

Which you could define as a constant in your class:

```
private static final Pattern LOTION_ENTRY = 
    Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))");
```

Then you can just create a `Matcher` for every entry and extract the groups:

```
Matcher matcher = LOTION_ENTRY.matcher(readLine);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    int no = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int rating = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    double discount = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(4));

    // do something
} else {
    // line doesn't match pattern, throw error or log
}
```

A note though: the `parseInt()` and `parseDouble` can throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not valid. So you'd have to catch those and act accordingly.